# Barra de progresso com css

Tags: html, css, css3

Bom estou tentando montar uma barra de progresso com css, sendo que o valor do progresso é de 13.20% O problema é que esta ficando um em efeito degradê, e quero que mude de uma cor para outra.

```css
.notification {
padding: 15px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    background:#F65314;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #F65314 13.20%, #000 86.80%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #F65314 13.20%, #000 86.80%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, #F65314 13.20%, #000 86.80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="notification">
  erwerwerwrwrwerw
</div>
```

Comment: Esse linear-gradient está chamando o efeito degradê, não?

Comment: Sim, usei ele para dar um exemplo do que eu quero fazer. Você sabe uma forma melhor de fazer essa barrinha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, o html5 possui uma opção para isso

```css
*,*:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: border-box

}

body{
background: silver;
}

.progress{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}

.progress .status{
  background: white;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.8
}
```

```html
<progress value="22" max="100"></progress>

<!-- Maneira com CSS e HTML -->

<div class="progress">
    <div class="status" style="width: 30%">30%</status>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente tem uma maneira melhor de fazer isso, mas uma das maneiras de fazer, pegando em base o seu código, é colocar o degradê sem transição entre uma cor e outra:

```css
.notification {
padding: 15px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    background:#F65314;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #F65314 13.20%, #000 13.20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="notification">
  Carregando
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como que os amigos mostrou pelo css. Se quiser tem a opção de fazer em bootStrap.

### Basic Progress Bar

13.20% Completo

Comment: <div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Progress Bar</h2>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:13.20%">
      <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: desculpe sou novo aqui